# Trying to implement a Breeze controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breeze

I am trying to implement a simple Breeze controller in Asp.Net MVC4, but can't seem to access it. Is it possibly conflicting with .Net's standard Web.Api ?

If my url is `http://localhost:49479/api/values` then I get a good return value from Web Api.

However if my url is `http://localhost:49479/breeze/Breeze` I get `"Http 404" error "Resource not found"`.

If my url is `http://localhost:49479/breeze/Breeze/5` I get error `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49479/breeze/Breeze/5'.`

Your advice is greatly appreciate.

Here's what I have in ..Controllers/BreezeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Breeze.ContextProvider;
using Breeze.WebApi2;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

   namespace RageSys.Controllers
   {
    [BreezeController]
    public class BreeezeController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> GetMtm(int id)
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
  }
```

and in BreezeWebApiConfig.cs :

```
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(RageSys.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
namespace RageSys.App_Start {
  ///<summary>
  /// Inserts the Breeze Web API controller route at the front of all Web API routes
  ///</summary>
  public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {

    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is named Breeeze controller with 3 e's...

Comment: thank you. I'm still getting the same error, though. Is there a conflict maybe with WebApi residing side by side ?

Comment: Nope not at all.  Your route is set up for breeze/{controller}/{action} but you are calling breeze/{controller} only.  Add the action...

Comment: @PWKad - so if I calling it as http://localhost:49479/breeze/breeze/5 why am I still getting the error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI. It does work when i call http://localhost:49479/api/values/5 , however.

Comment: Change it to something like breeze/breeze/GetMtm/1

Comment: that doesn't work either. I'll try starting a new project with a breeze template. I must be missing something. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The result you are getting from your `api/values` request is not coming from the listed controller. You must have the default `ValuesController` and `WebApiConfig` (which defines a route that takes a parameter) still in your project.

You do not have a route for `http://localhost:49479/breeze/Breeze/5`. The third segment (currently 5) needs to be the name of an Action method. For you, that means `GetMtm`. You do not have a route that takes any parameters, so you'll get nothing from: `http://localhost:49479/breeze/Breeze/GetMtm/5` unless you define such a route. You probably don't want to do this though, because Breeze coupled with Entity Framework will make life very easy. You should implement the simplest possible Breeze / Entity Framework application and see how it works from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using parameters and using Breeze, then ensure you use the .withParameters({ ParameterName: "Fred"}) or .withParameters({ id: id-value}), for example, in your Breeze query and ensure the parameter name in your function to be called (GetMtm in your case) at the server matches the parameter name you are using at the client.